# What is the Frege-Sense of "I am here"

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language

I am fairly familiar with Frege's usage of sense and reference, but how does he deal with indexicals?

Answer (score 3):

You can see some discussion about the possible "application" of Frege's theory to indexicals in the SEP entry about [Indexicals](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/indexicals/) : para **4.3 Some Alternatives to Kaplan's Theory**.

See also :

> Robert May, [Frege on Indexicals](http://philosophy.ucdavis.edu/people/rcmay/robert-mays-home-page/indexicals.pdf).